# How to modify connection string based on queue message in Azure WebJobs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have an Azure WebJob that needs to change which DB it connects to based on the queue message it is processing:

This queue message needs to access database CustomerOneDb:

`{"FormId":1, "DbName":"CustomerOneDb"}`

This queue message needs to access database CustomerTwoDb:

`{"FormId":2, "DbName":"CustomerTwoDb"}`

I assign the connection string when the `DBContext` is added, and I want to make it dynamic:

```cs
hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext.MyDbContext>(
        (serviceProvider, cfg) =>
        {
            if (!cfg.IsConfigured)
            {
                var cnString = "server=localhost;Initial Catalog={DbName};Integrated Security=True;";

                // TODO: Get DB name from queue message
                const string dbName = "CustomerOneDb";

                cnString = cnString.Replace("{DbName}", dbName);

                cfg.UseSqlServer(cnString);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

I haven't found any way to access the queue message from the context that calls `UseSqlServer`, so I'm looking for places where I *can* access the queue message, update some sort of variable, and then access that from inside `AddDbContext`.

FAILED ATTEMPT #1: Get it from the standard queue handler.

```cs
[FunctionName("ProcessQueueMessage")]
public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] QueueMessage queueMessage)
{
  // Process queue message
  // This runs *after* the code that calls UseSqlServer, so it's too late
}
```

FAILED ATTEMPT #2: Intercept the queue message by implementing `IQueueProcessorFactory`:

```cs
public class QueueData
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class MyQueueProcessorFactory : Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyQueueProcessorFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorOptions context)
    {
        return new MyQueueProcessor(_serviceProvider, context);
    }
}

public class MyQueueProcessor : QueueProcessor
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyQueueProcessor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, QueueProcessorOptions context) : base(context)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        Context = context;
    }

    internal QueueProcessorOptions Context { get; private set; }

    protected override Task<bool> BeginProcessingMessageAsync(QueueMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queueData = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<QueueData>();
        queueData.DatabaseName = "CustomerOneDb"; // TODO: Set variable based on value inside queue message

        return base.BeginProcessingMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`QueueData` is a scoped service:

```cs
hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    // ... other config omitted
    services.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessorFactory, MyQueueProcessorFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<QueueData>();
});
```

The function `BeginProcessingMessageAsync` runs *before* my call to `UseSqlServer`, which is great! However, when I retrieve the instance of `QueueData` later, it is always an empty string:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DbContext.MyDbContext>(
    (serviceProvider, cfg) =>
    {
        if (!cfg.IsConfigured)
        {
            // ...
            var queueData = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<QueueData>();
            var dbName = queueData.DatabaseName; // Always an empty string (unless QueueData is configured as a Singleton)
            // ...
        }
    }
);
```

FAILED ATTEMPT #3: Change `QueueData` to be a singleton:

`services.AddSingleton<QueueData>();`

This works! I can assign the DB name from `BeginProcessingMessageAsync` and retrieve it from within `AddDbContext`. **BUT... This is not a viable solution because the data is no longer scoped to the message that triggered the invocation.** That is, two messages coming in at the same time may compete with each other to set/retrieve the DB name on the same instance.

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
I can achieve my goal of dynamically setting the connection string based on info in the queue message if I can achieve any of these:

- Access the queue message from inside `AddDbContext`.
- Adjust the scope of QueueData so that when I assign it a value from `BeginProcessingMessageAsync` it is accessible later in `AddDbContext`
- Change QueueData to hold a collection of DbName values that are identified by a unique ID that I can then look up later from inside `AddDbContext`. The queue message ID would work but is not accessible from inside `AddDbContext`.

I'm stumped on how to do any of these options, so I'm asking for help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by updating the connection string from the queue handler.

```cs
[FunctionName("ProcessQueueMessage")]
public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] QueueMessage queueMessage)
{
  _repositoryService.SetFecContextDatabase(queueMessage.DatabaseName);
  // ...rest of implementation...
}
```

RepositoryService :

```cs
public class RepositoryService : IRepositoryService
{
    private readonly FecContext _context;
    
    public RepositoryService(FecContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SetFecContextDatabase(string dbName)
    {
        string currentCnString = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
        var cnString = currentCnString.Replace("{DbName}", dbName);
        _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString = cnString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to switch between "CustomerOneDb" and "CustomerTwoDb" on a single DBContext, I'd:

- Create and register a DBContext for each database
- Inject all DBContexts on the function class containing QueueTrigger
- Inside the QueueTrigger determine which DBContext to use.

If you have more than 2-3 databases then I'd suggest creating a DBContextFactory and inject it to the function class instead of many DBContexts.

Hope it helps!